# How to convert a number from 20,95 to 20.95 in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I get a String (20.95) from a spreadsheet and need to convert it to Double (20.95).

I tried using the [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, using

```
double.parse(NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_US').format(price)
```

but it always returns the value with a comma.

> Error: FormatException: Invalid double
> 20,95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code replaces the comma with a point and then parses it to a double.

```
double.parse(yourString.replaceAll(",", ".")),
```